# Replacing a word in a sentence with a another word

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

i was working on this question but there is some weird error in it. The problem is in the "Replace" function. I have commented the problem in the code below.

I made three dynamic character arrays (sentence, word1, word2) and used cin.getline to input. What i want to do is that if :

sentence = "I like pizza",

word1 = "like", and

word2 = "hate"

then I want sentence = "I hate pizza".

Also this is my first time using stack overflow so if there is any problem with this thread please let me know. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
 void Replace(char* s, char* w1, char* w2)
    {
        int lisw = 0; //lisw = letters in single word
        bool found = false;

        for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0' || found == true; i++)
        {
            lisw = 0;

            //Problem is down here. The loop doesn't terminate when encountering a
            //space character. When i used static_cast code to check the ASCII 
            //values only junk values were output. If i just cout<<s; then there is
            //no problem but doing it here causes some weird logical errors.
            for (int j = i; s[j] != ' '; j++)
            {
                lisw++;
                cout << static_cast<int>(s[j]);
            }

            found = true;

            for (int j = i; j < lisw; j++)
            {
                if (s[j] != w1[j])
                {
                    found = false;
                }

            }

            if (found == true)
            {
                for (int j = i; j < lisw; j++)
                {
                    s[j] = w2[j];
                }
            }

            i = i + lisw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have to use c-strings?  `std::string` makes this trivial.

Comment: Try to debug your program step by step with a paper and a pencil. I am sure you will find and fix all errors. Also think if `found` is true, you compare it with `true` and get `true`. If `found` is false, you compare it with `true` and get `false`. What do you think now, could you simply do `if (found)` without comparison?

Comment: @NathanOliver 

Yup. I have to use c-strings. I have not yet studied strings in my class so my teacher wants the solution with the stuff that has been taught only.

Comment: @S.M. The error seems very weird to me. Like when i just use cout<<s; the cstring is output correctly. When i use a for loop and output elements of 's' even then it is output correctly. However, when i do it the way i did in the above code there seems to an error. I used static_cast to see what were the ASCII values of the characters inside 's' and that gave me junk values.

Comment: @S.M 

As for your second question, i did it this way so that initially inside the loop 'found = true'. Then the code checks whether all the characters inside 'w1' are present inside 's'. If all of them are in fact present then 'found' remains 'true'. If even one character is different then 'found' becomes 'false'.

Comment: Unrelated: After pasting your code into the question, you can select the code and hit ctrl+k or use the {} button to autoformat.

Comment: `s[i] != '\0' || found == true` means stay in the loop if either of A) you haven't reached the end of the string B)  found is true. The first condition guarantees you're in the loop until the end of the string. Probably not what you want. The second condition just seems wrong. I would expect you want to leave the loop once you've found what you're looking for.

Comment: I mean another thing. When you have true, and compare it with true, you get true. When you have false, and compare it with true, you get false. `true` -> `true == true` -> `true`. `false` -> `false == true` -> `false`. I.e. `true` -> ... -> `true`. `false` -> ... -> `false`. Comparison is useless, isn't it?

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the ctrl k tip. I edited my post.

Ok so i will look into these conditions. Again thanks for the input.

Comment: @S.M. There may be a more efficient way but my bool conditions are working fine. I checked my other conditions and debugged my code. It finally works. :)

Comment: @user4581301 Your comment helped me the most. You were right. I was using wrong conditions. My code works now. Thanks!

Comment: Why people are still being taught C++ as "first the C uglyness that people rarely use, *then* the nice stuff that (competent) people actually use" continues to amaze and confuse me. It seems back-asswards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i found a solution thanks to the comments. I'll copy the corrected code below. The corrections can be seen in the comments.

```
 void Replace(char* s,char* w1, char* w2)
    {
        int lisw = 0; //lisw = letters in single word
        bool found =false;


        for (int i=0;s[i]!='\0' && found!=true;i++) //Replaced || with &&.
        {
            lisw=0;

            for (int j=i;s[j]!=' '&& s[j]!='\0';j++)//added: && s[j]!='\0' so the loop terminates because otherwise it kept finding "spaces" since the character array was of a larger size to accommodate any sentence. 
            {
                lisw++;

            }

            found=true;

            int k=0;

            for (int j=i;j<lisw+i;j++) //loop goes until lisw+i instead of lisw 
            {


                if (s[j]!=w1[k])
                {

                    found=false;
                }

                k++;

            }

            k=0;

            if (found==true)
            {
                for (int j=i;j<lisw+i;j++)//same as above.
                {
                    s[j]=w2[k];
                    k++;

                }
            }

            i=i+lisw;
        }
    }
```